# How to consume and produce messages with JSON schemas through the Kafka Console Consumer and Producer

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

Is it possible to consume and produce messages with JSON schemas in Kafka, using `kafka-console-consumer` and `kafka-console-producer` respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confluent Platform 5.5 adds [support for JSON Schema](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html) that also comes with `kafka-json-schema-console-consumer` and `kafka-json-schema-console-producer`.

---

**Consuming messages with JSON schema**

```
kafka-json-schema-console-consumer --topic myTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

**Producing message with JSON schema**

```
kafka-json-schema-console-producer \
    --broker-list localhost:9092 \
    --topic myTopic \
    --property value.schema='{"type":"object","properties":{"f1":{"type":"string"}}}'
```